# Local Notification passing value between controllers showing errors in swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I have developed my application in swift 4.0 and laster I have updated the Xcode with 10.2 , now it was stating lot of error which were working perfectly with previous version. I don't know how to fix these, I have attached the issue lines and wither issues.

1.Value of type 'Notification' has no member 'userInfo' (Error Name)

```
if let image = notification.userInfo?["image"] as? Int {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: image, section: 0)
            objtableview.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        }
```

2. Type 'Notification' has no member 'Name' (ERROR Name)

```
let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
```

3.Value of type 'Notification' has no member 'object' (ERROR Name)

```
 let reachability = notification.object as! Reachability // ERROR Line

        switch reachability.connection {
        case .none:
            debugPrint("Network became unreachable")
        case .wifi:
            debugPrint("Network reachable through WiFi")
        case .cellular:
            debugPrint("Network reachable through Cellular Data")
        }
```

4.Type 'Notification' has no member 'Name' (ERROR NAME)

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged),
                                               name: Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged,
                                               object: reachability)
```

5. 'Name' is not a member type of 'Notification' (ERROR NAME)

```
public extension Notification.Name { // ERROR LINe
    static let reachabilityChanged = Notification.Name("reachabilityChanged") //ERROR Line
}
```

6.Ambiguous reference to member 'post(name:object:)'

```
 func reachabilityChanged() {
        let block = connection != .none ? whenReachable : whenUnreachable

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            block?(strongSelf)
            strongSelf.notificationCenter.post(name: .reachabilityChanged, object: strongSelf) // ERROR LInE
        }
    }
```

Please check this and help me in clearing the issue

Comment: Do you have your own class or struct named Notification?